# How to deploy Rails App using private_pub to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, private-pub

I am trying to run my app on heroku which is using private_pub gem . Here in my local server I am running it perfectly . How can I push this app in heroku and run there perfectly . Here is my gem file :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails',                '4.2.1'
    gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
    gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
    gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
    gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
    gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
    gem 'bcrypt',               '3.1.7'
    gem 'mailboxer'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass',       '3.2.0.0'
    gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.1'
    gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
    gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
    gem 'faker',                '1.4.2'
    gem 'chosen-rails'
    gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
    gem 'private_pub'
    gem "thin"
    #gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'

    group :development, :test do
      #gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
      gem 'mysql2'
      #gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
      gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
      gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
       gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
    end


    group :test do
      gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
      gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
      gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
      gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
      gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
    end
```

And This is my private_pub.yml file :

```
  development:
          server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
          secret_token: "secret"
        test:
          server: "http://localhost:9292/faye"
          secret_token: "secret"
        production:
          server: "https://sheltered-sea-1191.herokuapp.com/faye"
          secret_token: "mysecret key"
          signature_expiration: 3600 # one hour
```

How can I push this app in heroku help me to push this on herok .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this above question I have created a new heroku app and I put this code as it is told in this tutorial https://webprogramming29.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/setup-privatepub-or-faye-on-heroku/

And then I edited my code using the following tutorial and it is working great